# Why did my API get duplicated in swagger?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, swagger

I created a couple of new APIs to request and calculate scores from a giver user, one is supposed to be a GET (Get Score), and the other one is just a PATCH (Calc Score), for whatever reason the later one got duped into an additional GET that I never made nor did I give it a URL, what did I do wrong? Can I fix it or is it an inherent property of PATCH methods to create an auxiliary GET?

[As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSubW.png)